# Does Azure service bus permission get passed onto its child topics and queues

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

In azure I have created a service bus. In the service bus I have created a topic. In the service bus there is a default RootManageSharedAccessKey shared access policy with manage send and listen permissions set.

Using the Microsoft.ServiceBus api I create an instance of the NameSpaceManager via the CreateFromConnectionString method which is the connection string I get from the  service bus level.

```
this.namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
```

[image]

The problem comes when I call

```
NamespaceManager.GetTopics();
```

I get this

[image]

Do child entities such as queues or topics need specific access rights? I would have thought the parent service bus permissions would cascade down and then I would have a choice to be more specific on the permissions for the child entities if needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does! My issue was because I had an extra character in my connection string.